# How to update jBoxes?

Tags: jbox

I have a form that uses jBox to provide additional info for some fields in tooltips. The text that is displayed depends on the value of the closest `select`-tag. jBox is executed on PageLoad (I create a single jBox which uses `data`-attributes to get title and content) and I then update the data-attributes in response to the `change`-event on the `select`-control.

Unfortunately that does not work, the tooltip stays with the initial value.

I have a cut-down repro with tooltip that illustrates the behaviour of not being updated (`alert`is used to show actual values of `data`-attributes after a change-event)

```js
$(function() {
  $("[data-jbox-content]").jBox("Tooltip", {
    theme: "TooltipDark",
    id: "jBoxTooltip",
    getTitle: "data-jbox-title",
    getContent: "data-jbox-content"
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/StephanWagner/jBox@v1.0.5/dist/jBox.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/StephanWagner/jBox@v1.0.5/dist/jBox.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Variable</th>
      <th colspan="2">Type</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="dt1">Car</label></td>
      <td><select id="dtCar" class="form-control select2 font-fas" name="dtCar" onchange="$('#infoCar').data('jbox-title','blabla');$('#infoCar').data('jbox-content','dummy');alert($('#infoCar').data('jbox-title')+' / ' + $('#infoCar').data('jbox-content'))">
          <option>Key</option>
          <option selected="selected">Boolean</option>
          <option>Ordinal</option>
          <option>Nominal</option>
          <option>Interval</option>
          <option>Ratio</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><span id="infoCar" data-jbox-content="This field can have one of two values: On or Off, Yes or No, 1 or 0." data-jbox-title="Description of the Boolean Scale">
          <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></span></td>
      <td><input id="inCar" class="form-control" name="inCar" type="text" value="Do you own a car?"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="dt2">Age</label></td>
      <td><select id="dtHouse" class="form-control select2 font-fas" name="dtAge" onchange="$('#infoAge').data('jbox-title','blabla');$('#infoAge').data('jbox-content','dummy');alert($('#infoAge').data('jbox-title')+' / ' + $('#infoAge').data('jbox-content'))">
          <option>Key</option>
          <option>Boolean</option>
          <option>Ordinal</option>
          <option>Nominal</option>
          <option selected="selected">Interval</option>
          <option>Ratio</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><span id="infoAge" data-jbox-content="This field can values from a defined interval, i.e. 0..200" data-jbox-title="Description of the Interval Scale">
          <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></span></td>
      <td><input id="inHouse" class="form-control" name="inAge" type="text" value="How old are you?"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a common misunderstanding of how jQuery uses `.data()` and `.attr()` methods.

`.data()` adds some internal data to the element itself and **will not** set an attribute.

To set a data-xxx attribute you need to use `.attr()`. See more here: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Also, check out updated snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $("[data-jbox-content]").jBox("Tooltip", {
    theme: "TooltipDark",
    id: "jBoxTooltip",
    getTitle: "data-jbox-title",
    getContent: "data-jbox-content"
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/StephanWagner/jBox@v1.0.5/dist/jBox.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/StephanWagner/jBox@v1.0.5/dist/jBox.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Variable</th>
      <th colspan="2">Type</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="dt1">Car</label></td>
      <td><select id="dtCar" class="form-control select2 font-fas" name="dtCar" onchange="$('#infoCar').attr('data-jbox-title','blabla');$('#infoCar').attr('data-jbox-content','dummy');">
          <option>Key</option>
          <option selected="selected">Boolean</option>
          <option>Ordinal</option>
          <option>Nominal</option>
          <option>Interval</option>
          <option>Ratio</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><span id="infoCar" data-jbox-content="This field can have one of two values: On or Off, Yes or No, 1 or 0." data-jbox-title="Description of the Boolean Scale">
          <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></span></td>
      <td><input id="inCar" class="form-control" name="inCar" type="text" value="Do you own a car?"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="dt2">Age</label></td>
      <td><select id="dtHouse" class="form-control select2 font-fas" name="dtAge" onchange="$('#infoAge').attr('data-jbox-title','blabla');$('#infoAge').attr('data-jbox-content','dummy');">
          <option>Key</option>
          <option>Boolean</option>
          <option>Ordinal</option>
          <option>Nominal</option>
          <option selected="selected">Interval</option>
          <option>Ratio</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><span id="infoAge" data-jbox-content="This field can values from a defined interval, i.e. 0..200" data-jbox-title="Description of the Interval Scale">
          <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></span></td>
      <td><input id="inHouse" class="form-control" name="inAge" type="text" value="How old are you?"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```